# Converting / Porting a C# app to a web based technology

Tags: c#, web, porting

Has anyone heard of a way to port or convert a C# desktop application to a suitable web technology. The important factors here would be high framerate, used for displaying flashing objects onto the display.

Or, alternately what is the best web language to use for a good response time (JS, Java Applet, etc). If anyone has done anything with similar requirements, what have you tried?

**EDIT:** It's a C# .NET 2.0 Windows standalone desktop application. I really don't know anything more, I was just wondering if any technology exists for any kind of C# application to any kind of web technology. This is for a job I'm applying to and I was just asking this for insight.

Comment: This really cant be answered with out knowing more about the app your wanting to port.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the simple answer to your question is "no". There are ways a skilled developer could re-write your solution in a different technology such as ASP.Net, ASP.Net MVC, Silverlight, etc, as others have said. But there is no wizard-like tool that could do that same thing.

Comment: Damn, well thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very subjective question, but I have been doing some web development that specializes in creating highly dynamic front end environments so I can give you my two cents.

You are a C# developer (which implies you have used .NET in the past). If you want to remain loyal to MS, you could try developing web application using their ASP.NET MVC frameworks. I would shy away from Silverlight as MS has no intention of actually enhance it from what I have heard (Build conference).

Personally, I have been using AngularJS, HTML5, D3.js to create highly interactive, data visualization applications that resemble in terms of interactiveness a desktop app.

EDIT:

On the last Build conference, it was easy to tell that MS was trying to push for web technologies over desktop technologies. They are pushing stuff like HTML5 and Typescript (which integrates nicely with VS). They had no mention of any desktop technology which infuriated quite few people. So, if you want to embrace the future: go for HTML5 and JavaScript (Typescript)

EDIT 2:

Links:

http://angularjs.org/ (A very easy to use MVC front end framework, it goes nicely with the ideas behind MVVM)

http://www.typescriptlang.org/ (Microsoft's favorite flavor of JS)

http://d3js.org/ (A very cool library for data visualization, if you are interested)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have Silverlight, which can use C# that can do serious graphics, but it probably doesn't have much of a future.  Microsoft has it on the axe list.

You could always use HTML 5 Canvas, which has very good support for complex graphics with high frame rates.  You are going to have to rewrite your code though.  I have never heard of anything which can convert a WinForms application to the web with any degree of reliability.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful as I don't quite know my way around web programming.